# Exporting prefab includes a lot of unneccessary asset dependencies

Tags: unity, assets, export

I just exported one of my assets into a `unitypackage`.
It included all dependencies very nicely so I can use them.

Then I tried another prefab, but it included a lot of unrelated assets from all over the project. This is a very simple prefab and I don't know how the clutter is considered to be dependencies.

When I click "show dependencies" it brings up the clutter in the project menu. There should be no clutter dependencies whatsoever. It really isn't that complex of a prefab.

I also double checked the prefab elements to see if any of them are somehow using the said clutter, they aren't.

How can this happen? Is there a way to solve it (other than selective clicking in export menu)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the solution. One of my elements had a script on it.
So that script was calling other scripts, which resulted in a spider web of dependencies, which also included a lot of seemingly unrelated assets.

I just exported the asset without the script and carried over the said script manually.

My scripts are pretty connected I guess.

I'm still open to better solutions if any.

Comment: Because of how C# works, Unity can't make very good guarantees about what scripts reference what other scripts. You might be referencing another script in a string somewhere, via SendMessage, GetComponent, or C# reflection. So if you have *any* custom script on the prefab, Unity has to assume it potentially references *all* your custom scripts, so it errs on the side of caution and includes the whole lot. You can deselect by hand any script files that you're not actually using.

Comment: Honestly there is not much you can do about this. Whenever I need to export a prefab or script from one of my work projects basically every asset is considered a dependency. Good code organization can minimize the issue but honestly I don't think Unity is particularly accurate when deciding which scripts are required.